# displaying a texarea value into another textarea value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've two input fields, both type textareas.

```
<input id="display" type="text" disabled="disabled" style="border: none; background: none" />
<input id="name" type="text" />
```

And I'm using jQuery to display the value of `#name` into `#display`. The textarea `#display` is used only for displaying. (It can be changed to any other suitable HTML element)

I use the jQuery code to do that:

```
$('#name').keyup( function() {
    $('#display').val($('#name').val());
});
```

The problem is, as I type, I want the value inside `#display` to wrap within its width. When I type long strings in `#name`, the string wraps and falls down as the next line but in `#display` it doesn't do so.

Again, when I type return, I want the same format to be followed up in the `#display` text field.

Can anyone tell me how do I do that??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need a `<textarea>`, not an input box if you want multiline text editing:

```
<textarea id="display" disabled="disabled" style="border: none; background: none; resize: none;"></textarea>
<textarea id="name" style="resize: none;"></textarea>
```

So to make the two look identical, your code should work:

```
$('#name').keyup(function() {
  $('#display').val($('#name').val());
});
```

I added `resize: none;` because it prevents the textareas from resizing via the little handle on the bottom-right-hand-corner (Webkit only).

Comment: It's kind of confusing to me, he said they were textareas but showed code for `<input>`...

Answer (score 1):

You could set a `white-space` property to `#display` and make it a `div` instead of an `input`

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html

```
#display {
    white-space:pre;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
    white-space:pre-line;
}
```

Any one of these values may be appropriate for you, see the link for reference and browser support.

I'm assuming you don't need to post the value of `#display`, so no need for a form element.